# In Azure Devops, what kind of permissions do you need to add a state?

Tags: azure, state, devops, addition

I can get to the page where you add a state, but the button cannot be used. I am an administrator. What type of permissions do I need to add a state?  Can I add a state with the free copy?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the built-in processes. Go to the list of processes and you should see a padlock next to Agile. Click the 3 dots menu and choose "Create inherited process" and you'll be able to modify the copy.